# How should I go about serving a json file to a website in my current architecture

Tags: c++, json, server

sorry for absolutly murdering the tilte. But I am not sure how to frame this question, please edit this if there is a better way of explaining my problem.

I am reading a bitstream from a program which I convert into json data, write it to a socket, where another program reads this data and appends it to a `log.json` file. I am doing all of this in **C++**

Now I want to display this data in a better way. So why not try to display this in an html document, with some css applied on it.

My first thought was to simply [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) this with javascript. But now-a-days this throws an [error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSRequestNotHttp).

So my second thought was to create a simple `node.js` server which accepts `GET` requests and then use this to serve the file. But this feels like its a bit overkill.

My third thought is now to perhaps use my original server (who continuously reads from the socket). And use that one to also accept http requests. But then I would have to multithread it, which again seems kinda overkill.

So im kinda falling back to needing 2 different "servers". One that reads from the socket and appends to the log file and another to serve this file to the website.

Am I'm thinking wrong here? What would be a good way to solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think those are **overkill**? are you limited in resource?

Comment: I'd say write a server by yourself is the overkill route. Use a small `node` app may adds dependency, but it's easy and fast (imho). And use a thread in `c++` doesn't really add much complexity afaict (I have no experience in c++ socket so I can be wrong).

Comment: if you only need to serve file, simply use existing server like  https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

Comment: Yea I will probobly go with the node alternative then!